# How to have function recall private variable between invocations

Tags: javascript

Here's an easy one straight from the text book I can't seem to find.

I have a javascript function. I want it to contain a *private* variable which remembers its value between invocations.

Can someone jog my memory please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create it using a closure:

```
function f() {
  var x = 0;
  return function() {return x++;};
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
> g = f()
function () {return x++}
> g()
0
> g()
1
> g()
2
```

Comment: @OP: This is the correct way to do this. Be aware, though, that there is a cost involved: Every call to `f` creates a *new* function, which can have memory implications. You can't rely on implementations reusing the underlying code and just creating a new environment for it every time (and in fact, I don't think most do, from my informal experiments). So there's the trade-off, you can get a truly private variable, but at a memory cost. Not important if there won't be many of these, but significant if there will.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var accumulator = (function() {
    var accum = 0;

    return function(increment) {
       return accum += increment;
    }
 })();

 alert(accumulator(10));
 alert(accumulatot(15));
```

Displays 10 then 25.

Comment: I guess it will display 10 and then 25?

Comment: @Artem:  Yes guess so to, I can program I just can't type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a truly private implementation

```
    (function() {

        var privateVar = 0;

        window.getPreviousValue = function(arg) {
            var previousVal = privateVar;
            privateVar = arg;
            return previousVal;
        }

    })()

    alert(getPreviousValue(1));
    alert(getPreviousValue(2));
```

Cheers

Comment: This won't create a *private* variable. It will be accessible from outside.

Comment: While it's always a good idea to remind people that functions are objects, your first example isn't even "privileged", it's completely public. *Anything* can look at `foo.privateVar`.

Comment: @tj - Ok, you are right. I was incorrectly applying the priveledged concept to a property when it rightly relates to a method. thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but maybe something like this would do the trick :

```
function Foo() {
  var x = "some private data";
  return {
   getPrivateData : function(){
      return x;
   }
  };
};

var xx = new Foo();
xx.getPrivateData();
```